# TSQL SELECT data within range of year and month

Tags: t-sql, date, datepart

I'm trying to query data within a range of start year and month and end year and month. But SQL returnes onty the year and the month chosen. Can anyone identify the problem with my approach.

Thanks!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE xxx 
(@JaarBegin AS int
, @JaarEind AS int
, @MaandBegin AS int
, @MaandEind AS int)

AS
BEGIN

WITH 
CTE AS
(
SELECT [D_Medewerker_ID]
      ,[Gebruikersnaam]
      ,[Naam]
      ,[Afdelingscode]
      ,CONVERT(date, [Datum_uit_dienst]) AS DatumIn
      ,CONVERT(date, [Datum_in_dienst]) AS DatumUit
FROM [DM].[dm].[D_Medewerker] AS M
), 
CTE2 AS(
 SELECT F.[D_Functie_ID] 
      ,[Generieke_Functie] 
      ,[Specifieke_Functie] 
      ,Fo.[D_Medewerker_ID]
  FROM [DM].[dm].[D_Functie] AS F
  JOIN dm.dm.F_FormatieBezetting AS Fo
  ON F.D_Functie_ID = Fo.D_Functie_ID
  )

SELECT DISTINCT CTE.[Gebruikersnaam]
, CTE.Naam
, CTE.Afdelingscode
, CTE.DatumIn
, CTE.DatumUit
, CTE2.Generieke_Functie
, CTE2.Specifieke_Functie
FROM CTE 
JOIN CTE2 
ON CTE.D_Medewerker_ID = CTE2.D_Medewerker_ID
WHERE DATEPART(year,CTE.DatumUit) BETWEEN @JaarBegin AND @JaarEind
AND DATEPART(MONTH, CTE.DatumUit) >= @MaandBegin AND DATEPART(MONTH, CTE.DatumUit) <= @MaandEind
ORDER BY CTE.DatumUit DESC;
END
```

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the int values you get to a date value.

In Sql server 2012 or later, you can use the built-in function [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) to do this:

```
WHERE CTE.DatumUit >= DATEFROMPARTS ( @JaarBegin , @MaandBegin , 1 )  
AND CTE.DatumUit < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS ( @JaarEind , @MaandBegin , 1 ))
```

If you are working with an earlier version of sql server, you need to build a string that represents the date (using iso format yyyy-mm-dd) and then cast it to date:

```
WHERE CTE.DatumUit >= CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@JaarBegin as varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@MaandBegin as varchar(2)), 2) +'-01' as datetime)
AND CTE.DatumUit < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(RIGHT('0000' +CAST(@JaarEind as varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@MaandBegin as varchar(2)), 2) +'-01' as datetime))
```

Comment: Nice, that worx.. Indeed I'm working with an earlier version. I'll have to look at your solution to get a better understanding of what is happening.